# Can Java's ThreadPoolExecutor act as a load balancer at application level?

Tags: java, load-balancing, threadpool, executorservice, threadpoolexecutor

Using ThreadPoolExecutor, we can define the maximum number of requests that a server should handle by limiting maximum number of threads.

Also, the ThreadPoolExecutor adds the extra incoming requests to the Thread Queue.

So, at the application level, a custom logic based on the application's requirements, can be written using ThreadPoolExecutor to limit or deny certain requests.

Therefore, can it act as a load balancer at application level?

Comment: Well, it doesn't really balance anything; a load balancer typically distributes tasks among several machines. Also, a load balancer should probably shed some load (i.e. deny requests) when the available resources are overwhelmed. ThreadPoolExecutor does neither of the two.
So, no, it isn't really a load balancer.

Comment: @danielkullmann, 2) point it is not really true. You can pass bounded queue to ThreadPoolExecutor's constructor and if queue is full, newly submitted task will be discarded. See RejectedExecutionHandler for details.

Comment: @IvanBabanin Ah! Thanks for clearing that up!

Answer (score 0):

In theory, we can optimize resource utilization by using `ExecutorService`s. In practice, there are some limitations. For example, what the `ThreadPoolExecutor` schedules are tasks. Tasks are run on Java-threads, which are mapped on OS-threads. A Java-thread cannot unload a task unless it is completed, either regularly or exceptionally. An OS-thread, however, can unload a Java-thread and load another process.

A consequence of the fact that a Java-thread cannot unload a non-completed task is that the system may be subjet to [Thread starvation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/starvelive.html): When (parent) tasks create new (child) tasks and parent tasks need the results of the child-tasks to continue, we can reach a point where all Java-threads are stuck on parent tasks that wait for child tasks to complete and no thread can make progress since no threads are available to execute the child tasks.

There are attempts to circumvent this bottleneck, e.g. the [`ForkJoinPool`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) may start additional `Thread`s to resolve thread starvation. It is, however, not guaranteed that thread starvation is always avoided or resolved (this is one reason why frameworks like vert.x or webflux deny blocking operations or delegate them to dedicated threads).

Furhtermore - [as was mentioned by daniel kullmann in the comments](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinPool.html) - a load balancer tries to balance the work. In `ThreadPoolExecutor`s, there is a shared queue and threads actively pull tasks, so no active balancing. Those are different concepts.

Comment: *"A thread in java is a green thread, it is not an OS thread."* - do you have a source to back that? I've read the opposite claim

Comment: @Joni [you were right](https://www.developer.com/java/data/an-introduction-to-jvm-threading-implementation.html). java threads map on OS-threads in the default threading model. Updating my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you accept a broad definition of "load balancing," yes, you can consider a ThreadPoolExecutor as a kind of a load balancer.

According to a broad definition of load balancing [like the one on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_(computing)):

> In computing, load balancing refers to the process of distributing a set of tasks over a set of resources (computing units), with the aim of making their overall processing more efficient.

With thread pool executor, the *tasks* are instances of `Runnable` or `Callable` that you need to run. The threads managed by the thread pool are the *resources* among which the tasks are distributed. The thread pool aims to make the overall processing efficient by making sure that no thread stays idle as long as there are tasks that need to be executed.

On the other hand, the way the question is worded suggests you are thinking about a different kind of load balancing: one where web service requests are distributed over server machines, and you wish to meet the demand for service while avoiding overloading any particular machine. In this scenario, you might use a ThreadPoolExecutor as a part of the load balancing system, but it's not a complete solution on its own: ThreadPoolExecutor only distributes tasks among threads on one machine. It does not have a way to respond to requests from remote machines, nor does it send tasks to remote machines.